# Mapstruct passing enclosed object to the mapping method

Tags: mapstruct

Is there a way to pass the enclosed object reference as a parameter to the mapping method?

```
public class Car {
   public int id;
   public Person driver;
}
public class Person {
   public int carId;
}
```

I need a reference to the enclosing car object when mapping the person object in the `personToPersonDtoAfterMapping` custom method.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CarMapper {

    public abstract CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
    public abstract PersonDto personToPersonDto(Person person);
    @AfterMapping
    protected void personToPersonDtoAfterMapping(Person person, @MappingTarget PersonDto dto,  Car enclosedCar) {
        dto.setCarId(enclosedCar.getId())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use @Context annotation. Did you try?

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CarMapper {

    public abstract CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
    public abstract PersonDto personToPersonDto(Person person, @Context Car enclosedCar);
    @AfterMapping
    protected void personToPersonDtoAfterMapping(Person person, @MappingTarget PersonDto dto, @Context Car enclosedCar) {
        dto.setCarId(enclosedCar.getId())
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, mapstruct will implement two methods in the mapper - one with the context and one - without the context. However the top level mapping will use the one without the context, so your second and third method won't be used..
You would have to use
` abstract CarDto carToCarDto(Car car, @Context car car);`